# How to account for Properties.Settings.Default in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm referencing a third-party DLL that reads configuration from `Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultHostName`. How do I configure this in my ASP.NET 5 application so that their call to Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultHostName doesn't cause an exception?

In previous versions of ASP.NET this would have appeared in the web.config as

```
<applicationSettings>
  <DllName.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="DefaultHostName" serializeAs="String">
      <value>Sample</value>
    </setting>
  </DllName.Properties.Settings>
<applicationSettings>
```

It's not clear whether ASP.NET 5 overrides the `System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider` (used by ApplicationSettings by default) to use the new configuration services, but I did try using

```
Configuration.Set( "DllName:Properties:Settings:setting:DefaultHostName:value", "Sample" );
```

without any noted effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known way to make this work.

See https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the xml configuration tests for ASP.NET 5: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Xml.Test/XmlConfigurationSourceTest.cs#L157-L177

For your particular case, the configuration key should be:

`DllName:Properties:Settings:setting:DefaultHostName:value`

Comment: I used Configuration.Set( "DllName:Properties:Settings:setting:DefaultHostName:value", "Sample" ); but this seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Are you trying to generate that xml or what's your scenario?

Comment: The application has to make the values available so that the third-party dll doesn't crash when it is looking for them.

Comment: It uses Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultHostName see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx. By default these settings are read from an exml file.